# Iterating through a nested FormField

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to iterate through a FormField in a Formfield, which are both part of a FieldList.

In my `views.py` I'm calling for the `mainForm`, the template iterates successfully through the FormField `subForm`. However, when I can't get the iteration through the `subSubForm` to work. Those fields never appear in the browser.

Formcode:

```
class subSubForm(Form):
    step = IntegerField("step", validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=99)])
    description = TextField("Description")
    information = TextAreaField("Information Exchanged")])

class subForm(Form):
    name = TextField("Description")
    step = FieldList(FormField(subSubForm), min_entries=1)

class mainForm(Form):
   sub_form = FieldList(FormField(subForm), min_entries=1)
```

And the Jinja2 template:

```
{% for sub_form in form.sub_form %}
      {{ sub_form.form.name(placeholder='Scenario Title') }}
      {% for error in name %}
             {{error}}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for step in form.sub_form %}
            {{ step.form.id(placeholder='#') }}  
            {{ step.form.description(placeholder='description') }}
            {{ step.form.information(placeholder='info xch') }}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above only shows the `sub_form.form.name`-field.
How can I do nested iteration so that the `step` fields are also shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you made mistake in second nested loop in your template. Here is its fixed version:

```
{% for sub_form in form.sub_form %}
      {{ sub_form.form.name(placeholder='Scenario Title') }}
      {% for error in name %}
             {{error}}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for step in sub_form.step %}
            {{ step.form.step(placeholder='#') }}  
            {{ step.form.description(placeholder='description') }}
            {{ step.form.information(placeholder='info xch') }}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This renders to:

```
<input id="sub_form-0-name" name="sub_form-0-name" placeholder="Scenario Title" type="text" value="">
<input id="sub_form-0-step-0-step" name="sub_form-0-step-0-step" placeholder="#" type="text" value="">  
<input id="sub_form-0-step-0-description" name="sub_form-0-step-0-description" placeholder="description" type="text" value="">
<textarea id="sub_form-0-step-0-information" name="sub_form-0-step-0-information" placeholder="info xch"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found it myself as well :)